# No Karma report on singlerun = false

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mocha.js, karma-runner

I wonder if I am missing something trivial here, but I can not see any test reports if I have set up singlerun to true in karma config. It only shows that the browsers were launched and that is it. I can click on **DEBUG** and inspect the browser console log that way, but I would feel that one should be also see the results in the terminal too.

Thanks for the help!

> My karma.config.js:
>
> ```
> basePath: '../',
>
> // start these browsers
> // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
> browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
>
> frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai'],
>
> files: [
>   { pattern: 'test/vendor/indexeddbshim.min.js', watched: false },
>   { pattern: 'tests.webpack.js', watched: false },
> ],
>
> preprocessors: {
>   'tests.webpack.js': ['webpack'],
> },
>
> webpack: {
>   resolve: {
>     root: [
>       path.resolve('./test/vendor'),
>     ],
>     alias: {
>       backbone: 'backbone',
>       underscore: 'underscore',
>     },
>   },
>   module: {
>     loaders: [
>       {
>         // test: /^\.js$/,
>         exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|vendor)/,
>         loader: 'babel-loader',
>       },
>     ],
>   },
> },
>
> webpackServer: {
>   noInfo: true,
> },
>
> // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
> autoWatch: false,
>
> // test results reporter to use
> // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
> // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
> reporters: ['progress'],
>
> // web server port
> port: 9876,
>
> // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
> colors: true,
>
> // Continuous Integration mode
> // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
> singleRun: false,
>
> plugins: [
>   require('karma-webpack'),
>   require('karma-mocha'),
>   require('karma-chai'),
>   require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
>   require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
> ],
> logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,   });
> ```

Comment: Setting `singleRun: false` assumes that you are explicitly start the karma-client manually. This means that you start `karma` (technically the `karma-server`), then go to another terminal and type `karma run`. Setting `singleRun: true` in your karma configuration will call `karma run` for you. Here's the doc: http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/plus/requirejs.html

Comment: Great, thanks, this helped me a lot!

Comment: @MarcoL You should rewrite your comment as an answer for this question.  That was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Done, glad it worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the comment above:

Setting `singleRun: false` assumes that you are explicitly start the karma-client manually.

This means that you start karma (technically the karma-server), then go to another terminal and type `karma run`.

Setting `singleRun: true` in your karma configuration will call karma run for you.

Here's the doc: 
[Karma configuration - requirejs version](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/plus/requirejs.html)