# Angular Unit tests with Chrome headless and Karma hangs on

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, google-chrome-headless

I'm using Chrome-Headless to run my **Angular 7**  unit tests project with **Karma**

It seems to not be stable as when running dozens of specs , **it breaks randomly** at any test without completing all tests.

I don't know if it's a probleme of memory , of chrome itself of karma..

**My karma.conf :**

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html
var process = require('process');

module.exports = function (config) {

  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, 'coverage'),
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },

    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
      ? ['progress', 'coverage-istanbul']
      : ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    browserDisconnectTimeout: 60000,
    browserDisconnectTolerance: 3,
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 60000,
    flags: [
      '--disable-web-security',
      '--disable-gpu',
      '--no-sandbox'
    ],
    singleRun: true,
    concurrency: Infinity
  });
};
```

And i'm using thos testing packages :

```
"jasmine-core": "^3.3.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
"karma": "^4.0.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
"karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.0.4",
"karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
```

**Suggestions ??**

Answer (score 4):

add a customer luncher for it, it should fix the problem

```
browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox'],
customLaunchers: {
  ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
    base: 'ChromeHeadless',
    flags: ['--no-sandbox']
  }
},
```

here is an example of a working config using ChromiumHeadless

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-junit-reporter'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['junit','progress', 'kjhtml'],
    junitReporter: {
      outputDir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'), // results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName.xml
      outputFile: 'junit.xml', // if included, results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName/$outputFile
      suite: '', // suite will become the package name attribute in xml testsuite element
      useBrowserName: false, // add browser name to report and classes names
      nameFormatter: undefined, // function (browser, result) to customize the name attribute in xml testcase element
      classNameFormatter: undefined, // function (browser, result) to customize the classname attribute in xml testcase element
      properties: {}, // key value pair of properties to add to the <properties> section of the report
      xmlVersion: null // use '1' if reporting to be per SonarQube 6.2 XML format
    },
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    singleRun: false,
    browsers: ['Chrome_no_sandbox'],
    customLaunchers: {
      Chrome_no_sandbox: {
        base: 'ChromiumHeadless',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: ; i may replace ChromiumHeadless with ChromeHeadless , no ?

Comment: wele i'm looking to keep both Chrome and ChromeHeadless to work with both of them according to choice , so i put:    browsers: ['Chrome', 'Chrome_no_sandbox'],  , and i would try run it with this ng test --browsers=Chrome_no_sandbox--watch=false --code-coverage  ... what you say about this ?

Comment: ng test will run with the config you have by default, ig you want to run using Chrome use : ng test --browsers Chrome

Comment: well i ve tested the general behaviour , running tests keeps breaking randomly .. this haven't improve it

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I resolved it by:

- Add the latest version of puppeteer (1.19.0) and karma-chrome-launcher (3.1.0):

`yarn add -D puppeteer karma-chrome-launcher`

- Wire them in such corky way in my `karma.conf.js` ():

```
process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('puppeteer').executablePath();

module.exports = config => {
  config.set({
    // other config options...

    // custom ChromeHeadless launcher
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadless_without_security'],
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadless_without_security: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: ['--disable-web-security', '--disable-site-isolation-trials']
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Upvoting because this is recommended in [karma-chrome-launcher README](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher#headless-chromium-with-puppeteer).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue while running tests for a small web application.  I have **Angular**(*14.2.9*) and **NodeJS**(*19.0.1*) on **RHEL**(*8.7*).  This is being done on a Jenkins agent that is an **EC2** instance configured to have the master remotely login and do the work.

I have a Jenkins pipeline setup that:

- Pulls from the code repository
- Installs all the dependencies
- Builds the web application
- Runs the tests

Very standard stuff, nothing unusual.  However, when the final stage went to complete in the Jenkins pipeline it wouldn't exit.  The logs showed the tests were successful but it wouldn't exit and finish.

```
09 11 2022 22:34:06.555:INFO [Chrome Headless 109.0.5396.2 (Linux x86_64)]: Connected on socket xm4ZTAjwGMOgGuePAAAB with id 1783772
Chrome Headless 109.0.5396.2 (Linux x86_64): Executed 0 of 4 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
[1A[2KChrome Headless 109.0.5396.2 (Linux x86_64): Executed 1 of 4 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.117 secs)
[1A[2KChrome Headless 109.0.5396.2 (Linux x86_64): Executed 2 of 4 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.143 secs)
[1A[2KChrome Headless 109.0.5396.2 (Linux x86_64): Executed 3 of 4 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.153 secs)
[1A[2KChrome Headless 109.0.5396.2 (Linux x86_64): Executed 4 of 4 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.16 secs)
[1A[2KChrome Headless 109.0.5396.2 (Linux x86_64): Executed 4 of 4 SUCCESS (0.188 secs / 0.16 secs)
TOTAL: 4 SUCCESS
```

Upon reading over the `karma.conf.js` file I came across the field `singleRun` and it was set to `false`.

This seemed strange and didn't intuitively make logical sense so I changed it to `true`.  When I re-ran the pipeline the tests finished and exited without issue.

I did some further research and found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36582751/1230086) that without this set then you are expected to manually start the karma-client.